# Mocked date causes error in jasmine test using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, momentjs

I have a function that I have updated to use Moment JS for comparing two dates. The function works fine, but the test is failing stating that `undefined is not a function (evaluating Date.UTC)`. Here is a dumbed down version of the test (Jasmine):

```
var dateChecker,
    $rootScope;

var AppParams = {
    dateToCheck: '9/1/2015'
};

beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $rootScope.AppParams = AppParams;
}));

var createDate = function (year, month, date) {
    var overrideDate = new Date(year, month, date);
    spyOn(window, 'Date').andCallFake(function () {
        return overrideDate;
    });
};

describe('check date', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        createDate(2015, 12, 10);
        inject(function (_dateChecker_) {
            dateChecker = _dateChecker_;
        });
    });

    it('should return 1/1/2016', function () {
        var dates = dateChecker.checkDate();
        expect(dates.length).toBe(1);
        expect(_.contains(dates, '01/01/2016')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

And here is a dumbed down version of the function it is testing:

```
this.checkDate = function () {
            var dates;
            var dateToCheck = $rootScope.AppParams.dateToCheck;
            var today = moment();
            if (today.isAfter(moment(dateToCheck, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'day')) {
                dates = [
                    '01/01/2016'
                ];
            }
            return dates;
        };
```

After taking the function apart piece by piece, I have determined the error is occurring when evaluating `moment(dateToCheck, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`. I have verified that both `today` and `dateToCheck` are both getting assigned correctly.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

[Fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/rdsxtqkn/)

Comment: Are you on the latest 2.11.1, or something earlier?

Comment: 2.5.1 but I've tried it on 2.11.1 with the same results.

Comment: We had a date-mocking issue in 2.11.0 ([#2858](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/2858)), but that was fixed in 2.11.1.  I'll look closer.  (Still, I recommend updating.)

Comment: One thing (probably not the issue), but you're forgetting that months are 0-11.  Month 12 doesn't exist.  when `createDate` calls the date constructor, it should subtract one.

Comment: That's true but it is not the issue here. My months are 0 based in the actual test, I incorrectly put 12 there when "dumbing down" the test.

Comment: Agreed.  It would be helpful if you could repo it in a jsFiddle (or similar)?

Comment: Also, perhaps you might consider using the new date mocking feature (added in 2.11.0, stable in 2.11.1).  See tests with usage [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.11.1/src/test/moment/now.js#L15-L56).  Basically, you set a function in `moment.now` that returns the timestamp (ms since the unix epoch).  -  (though I still do want to get to the bottom of this)

Comment: Oh, just realized there are indeed [docs for this new feature](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/).  :)

Comment: OK. I'll see if I can getting a working jsFiddle example. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to actually upgrade to 2.11.1 so I'll look into that. They are a little finicky here about which versions they allow.

Comment: Added a jsFiddle example.